# Inconsistency in two equations for Planck law given by professor

Tags: thermal-radiation, frequency

I know there are a variety of questions about this topic but I have been searching the internet for a long time and couldn't find a proper answer. The question is simple:

I saw the following formula in my professor's notes for Planck's formula:

$$I(\nu,T) = \dfrac{2\pi h \nu^3}{c^2} \dfrac{h\nu}{e^{h\nu/kT}-1} .$$

However, wherever I look I have seen it in a form such that:

$$I(\nu,T) = \dfrac{2\pi h \nu^3}{c^2} \dfrac{1}{e^{h\nu/kT}-1} .$$

Simply without a $h\nu$ term. Why? What is the difference exactly? Was my professor just make a mistake?

Comment: I don’t recognize the first formula. My guess is that it’s a mistake. I suggest asking your professor.

Comment: I will, as soon as possible. Then I will update it.

Comment: What is $I$ in the first place?  Intensity of what?  Power? Energy per frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turnes out to be a mistake by the professor. Second formula is correct.